# Implementation of methods is not available Error

Tags: api, kotlin, intellij-idea, decompiler

Hi I tried to use some external libraries but at first I cannot access to the files of this library and got this error:

```
// This class file was compiled with different version of Kotlin compiler and can't be decompiled.

// Current compiler ABI version is 1.1.16
// File ABI version is 1.5.1
```

But I partially solved by going to
Tools->Kotlin->Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates

and updating.

Now I get access to the files but now the error that I having is that in some files in the header of the file it says:

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available
```

Any idea of what may it be? And how to solve it?

Thank you very much

Comment: do you want to see the source code of the library?

Comment: Idea doesn't have a Kotlin decompiler. Please check that you have the actual source code of these external libraries. Then it should display the source code in the IDE. If it doesn't - it's likely a bug, please report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KTIJ with a sample project to reproduce attached.